# how to call a dll file in c. I want to transmit a xml file to it

Tags: c++, c, xml, dll

I found many ways, but they are too easy, they always get a return-value from the dll file.

dll file: a file with the sufix ".dll"

Comment: Uh... I have absolutely *no* clue what you're trying to say...

Comment: *I found mangy manners...* Huh?

Comment: Did you mean "many" ways rather than "mangy" ways? Anyway, it's not at all clear what you're actually trying to do. We know what a dll is--but it's impossible to tell from your question what you're really trying to do with the dll and what it means to "transmit a xml file" to the dll.

Comment: Also, thanks for defining what a dll file is. It wasn't clear to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close, as the OP hasn't put any effort into clarifying the question (other than defining "dll"?!), and there's just no way to tell what he wants based on this.

Comment: Sorry. My English is really poor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just like any other WINAPI

```
// assuming you are using windows
LPCTSTR lpszXml = _T("<xml> </xml>");
TCHAR szResult[1000] = _T("");
HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary(_T("mylibrary.dll"));
int (*DoWorkFunc)(LPCTSTR lpszXmlData, LPTSTR lpszResult, int cchMaxSize);

*(FARPROC*)&DoWorkFunc = GetProcAddress(hModule, _T("DoWork"));
int nLength = DoWorkFunc(lpszXml, szResult, 1000);
_tprintf(_T("input [%s] output [%s] length of the result [%d]\n")
         , lpszXml, szResult, nLength);

FreeLibrary(hModule);
// warning: no error handling is performed
```

**Edit:**
Since I speak multiple-languages, I can roughly guess what the OP asked. It is probably along this line:

> I found many ways [in the internet] to load a DLL file and call a function inside it. But those that I found involve simple functions like `int add(int a, int b)`. They only get a return value from the function. What I want to do is to pass a big chunk of data and get another big chunk of data from the function. How can I pass a big chunk of data and get a big chunk of data as the return value?